# C# program does not work in the deployed client. Mysql Connector error

Tags: c#, mysql, deployment, mysql-connector

I have created an application in visual studio that uses Mysql Connector to access a database of a server. When starting the program in the developing PC it works fine. When i install this program in another PC after some seconds after running there pop ups a error such :

```
  Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01:    ServiceHoster.exe
  Problem Signature 02:    1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03:    59516cb4
  Problem Signature 04:    MySql.Data
  Problem Signature 05:    6.9.9.0
  Problem Signature 06:    5764222b
  Problem Signature 07:    712
  Problem Signature 08:    59
  Problem Signature 09:    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySql
  OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1031
  Additional Information 1:    0a9e
  Additional Information 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3:    0a9e
  Additional Information 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

When i Debug, on the client machine using visual studio i get the following exception:

```
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at DataExchangeLayer.DataExchange.SyncTrainersFromBackendToFrontend()
   at ServiceHoster.ViewModel.MainViewModel.UpdateBackendWithFrontend()
   at ServiceHoster.ViewModel.MainViewModel.Timer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at ServiceHoster.App.Main()
```

Connection string is as following:

```
Server=server;Port=some_port;database=database_name;Uid=username;Pwd=password;persistsecurityinfo=True
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show your MySQL connection string, with username and password redacted. Can you connect to your MySQL server from the machine in question using an ordinary MySQL client (the `mysql` command line client, HeidiSQL, or the Workbench, for examples?) If not, please [edit] your question to show the error from one of those clients.

Comment: Hello, yes i can connect to the database from a workbench. @O.Jones